# UK Citizen applying for Indian Business Visa

Tags: visas, india, uk-citizens

I’m looking for a faster way of applying for an Indian Business Visa in the UK. Our online E-visa application option has been removed and have to wait until after Christmas for an appointment with VFS!! I need to be in India beginning November. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The citizens from the UK, Canada and China *(and others...)* have been indeed [removed](https://publictechnology.net/articles/news/pm-%E2%80%98raised-concerns%E2%80%99-over-uk%E2%80%99s-e-visa-exclusion-last-visit-india) from the e-Visa list, and the only alternative is to get a paper visa.

Contrary to some other countries, VFS (the commercial partner of the Government of India for visa services) doesn't allow to pay for priority so, apart from finding an appointmemt, in the UK you're out of options.
And you can't apply abroad either, as they require the sponsoring business to be based, and the applicant to reside in the country of application.

Comment: UK visa is hard to obtain for an Indian citizen. Requires complex application process and all. Probably Indian governments way to push UK government for a simpler process.

Comment: [Follow-up question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/76272/36308)